# Why root password exist if I can be root with sudo -s or sudo -i, it need only sudo password so?

Tags: permissions, sudo, password, root

`sudo -i` makes me root with **sudo** password

`sudo -s`, `sudo su` the same

`su` and `su root` need **root** password so it doesn't make sense to me, I can be root with only sudo password so why root password exist?

Comment: By default there is no root password. Password access for the root user is disabled. Why did *you* set a root password?

Comment: So why it is possible to set root password?

Comment: A root password exists to be able to login as root. Usually the user root is handled with special care, often makes root the only user which is able to login into a system when a critical system error occurred. For example, when your `/home` directory is mounted on a different drive and this drive has a malfunction and Linux cannot mount it - this making every user unable to login, but the root user may still be able to login, cause his home directory is `/root`.

Comment: @paladin the root user is a user, why shouldn't it be possible to set a password for them? It's perfectly possible to have a system without `sudo`, after all.

Comment: Also, when you want to change the home directory of a user, that user shouldn't be logged in. For example, user john wants to change his home directory, usually only a superuser may change a home directory. Doing sudo as user john won't help, because user john probably can't change his own home directory while logged in. So you would logout and login as root and change home directory of user john.

Comment: @paladin for example I have two users on my linux, peter and john. peter is in sudo and he is the owner of pc, john is also in sudo but peter don't want john to be able to use root account, so only peter knows root password but john still can be root because he is in sudo so he can just use sudo -i and that's it?

Comment: @pjk Whoever has sudo rights is also able to login into root account without password.

Comment: okay now I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is quite simple. On Ubuntu, the root password *does not* exist. The root account is not enabled. Thus, the root user cannot login on a standard Ubuntu system.

Instead there is the `sudo` system where selected "normal" users can assume administrator priviledges. So if you want a terminal with root privileges, `su` will not work, because `root` is not active. However, you still can obtain such prompt with `sudo -i`, where you act as a privileged normal user, thus provide your own user password.

See here for a more elaborate discussion of `sudo` versus logging in to the root account. You will learn you *can* activate the root account. If you then ask *"Why root password exist if I can be root with sudo -s or sudo -i, it need only sudo password so?"*, well, in this case it is *you* who created the contradictory situation. By default, that situation is not there.

Comment: Okay now I'm really close to understand it but I have one more question from my comment above, let me copy it: 

for example I have two users on my linux, peter and john. peter is in sudo and he is the owner of pc, john is also in sudo but peter don't want john to be able to use root account, so only peter knows root password but john still can be root because he is in sudo so he can just use sudo -i and that's it?

In this situation john should't be in sudo group to avoid it?

Comment: `sudo su` will work, or just `sudo passwd` will enable any sudo-user to set a root-password.

Comment: @pjk being administrator is a job of trust. If there are two root users that do not trust each other, then that has to be solved at the management level, not at the level of the operating system ;) So indeed, one can be taken away root privileges if need be (and if that person did not yet destroy the system yet).

Comment: @paladin yes, root can do everything, including activating the root account. Being administrator is a job of trust.

Comment: Being able to have root access _without_ a password still have its advantages - for instance you can still login as root with SSH keys even if the password is not set. This is far more secure than using a password.